# How can I centrally import a TypeScript class into an Angular Module?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a recommended method for importing TypeScript classes into an Angular Module so that every Component or Service in that Module inherits those definitions?

The core issue is **"why doesn't a class imported into a module get automatically imported into the other components in that module?"**

I have tried importing a class into the module like this:

registration.model.ts:

```
export class Event {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

registration.module.ts:

```
import { Event } from './registration.model';
```

I have also added it to the declarations in the Module with no effect (I removed this from the declarations array as soon as I figured out it did nothing):

```
declarations: [
    Event,
    ...
]
```

registration.service.ts:

```
getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {

  return this.http.get(`api/events`)
    .map(response => response.json());

}
```

Produces this error and the app fails to compile:

> ERROR in
>   C:/code/registration/src/app/registration/registration.service.ts
>   (26,29): Cannot find name 'Event'.

If I add the import directly into registration.service.ts then the error goes away and everything compiles properly:

```
import { Event } from './registration.model';
```

I have verified that the relative path is correct in the Module.  I can change it to an absolute path in the Module and will I get the same error in the service.

**Follow-Up Edit**
Thanks to Adrian's response I understand this a lot better now.  I also found out that you can import several classes at once from a TypeScript module as follows:

```
import * as Registration from 'app/models/registration.model';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it works. In order to use the Event model class in other parts of your application you need to import it in each and every of them. It's irrelevant if you use or not NgModule.

NgModule is used by the [Angular compiler](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#q-angular-compiler), but before it gets to that step the TypeScript compiler needs to handle your code.

In every file where you want to use this you need to import it, just like you did in the module (probably the path might be different in each case):

```
import { Event } from './registration.model';
```

Otherwise TypeScript will have no idea what Event is and where to get it from.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

> Error itself says can't find name Event

**The problem is with your relative path. Relative path is not correct**

---

For information purpose:

Don't need to mention **`Event class`** in **`declarations metadata property`**. You should mention something in **`declaration array`** when a class has to do something with ***`Angular context`*** meaning when class is defined with **`@Component decorator`**. 
Since you are using a pure Typescript class just import **`Event`** class in **`registration.service.ts`**

**registration.service.ts**

```
import { Event } from './registration.model or correct relative path';

getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {   // Now Event[] is declared and will not issue any error.

  return this.http.get(`api/events`)
    .map(response => response.json());

}
```

Comment: Please look at the last few lines of my Question, I'm aware that I can import it directly into the Service.  That's not answering my question though.

Comment: Okay. Then it seems you have a problem with relative path. Relative path is not correct.

Comment: I am 100% positive that the module and the service are both in the same directory, otherwise the service wouldn't work when I add the import.  VS Code is not showing any errors with my import statement in the Module either.

Comment: @micronyks is correct, probably problem is in somewhere else.

Comment: Adding it to the declarations has zero impact on how the code works, so of course I have removed it.  @asmmahmud I'm not having problems, I'm looking for a more efficient way to import class definitions.